# Server doesnt responds to javascript code while entering a line of text in the input field

Tags: javascript, php

```
function removeEditor() {
    if ( !editor )
        return;
    document.getElementById( 'inputbox' ).innerHTML = html = editor.getData();
    var data=encodeURIComponent(html);
    var topic=document.getElementById('currentField').value;
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML="Updating...";
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "Report_Viewer.php");
    if(topic!=""){
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                document.getElementsByName('btnupdate').item(0).style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('popup').style.display="block";
                document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML=ajax.responseText;

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display="none";
    }, 5000);
            }
        }
        ajax.send("data="+data+"&topic="+topic);
        }   
            document.getElementById( 'inputbox' ).style.display = '';
            editor.destroy();
            editor = null;
        }

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        include_once("php_include/db_conx.php");
        $topic= $_POST['topic'];
        $comment=($_POST['data']);
        $count=str_word_count(strip_tags(strtolower($comment)));
        if($count>2500 && ($topic=='introduction' || $topic=='reviewofliterature') ){
            echo "Can not save more than 2500 words";
            exit();
        }else if($count>30 && $topic=='title'){
            echo "Can not save more than 30 words as title";
            exit();
        }else if($count>600 && $topic=='methodology'){
            echo "Can not save more than 600 words as Methodology";
            exit();
        }else if($count>600 && $topic=='objective'){
            echo "Can not save more than 300 words as Aims & Objectives";
            exit();
        }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_synopsis WHERE studentid='$uid'";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($num_rows>0){
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_synopsis SET $topic='$comment' WHERE studentid='$uid'";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            echo "Updated";
            exit();
        }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_synopsis(studentid,$topic) VALUES('$uid', '$comment')";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

            echo "Inserted";
            exit();
        }
        }
    }
?>
```

when i enter this line of text to input field

> COMPARATIVE STUDY ON EFFICACY OF OMEPRAZOLE WITH PANTOPRAZOLE FOR THE
>   PREVENTION AND TREATMENT OF NSAIDs RELATED ACID PEPTIC DISODERS.

and press update button which calls `removeEditor()` function then server stops responding, but when i run this code locally and enter same text in the field then it does work properly. What's wrong with this code or its hosting server's problem?

Comment: I would start by checking the path of the files that sit on the server. I haven't checked the syntax of your code yet, but I'm assuming it's fine since this runs correctly locally. Double check if path of `Report_Viewer.php` or `php_include/db_conx.php` are correct and verified on the server.

Comment: i already checked and i have run same code to another web server(online) it works perfectly. But in one hosting server(online)it stops responding and my public ip get suspended for 10-20 minutes.

Comment: if i enter other line of text instead of the one mentioned above, it works perfectly but i don't know what is wrong with that line of text. When i enter that line server stops responding and my IP get blocked.